# Submit button disabled changes color in Opera

Tags: css, submit, opera

I have problem with a button in Opera, notated by `input type=["submit"]` disabled.

In CSS, I have set a white font color, and when I click on this submit button, the color changes to gray.

This happens only in Opera.

Hint: `input[disabled="disabled"]` doesn't work!

Comment: do you have an online example?

Comment: can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ or put some code then? Maybe you could use a reset css, sound like it might be an opera thing. Did you try other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The article ["Styling disabled form controls with CSS"](http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/disabled/) recommends the syntax

```
[disabled]{ /*you rules here*/ }
```